# Query using CASE in left outer join takes long time to run

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

I am running a Postgres query with a `CASE` expression in a join condition. The query takes a long time to run. Is there a better way to optimize this query?

Code snippet:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN analyticsdatamart_gen_nontemporal_v1.dimension_organisations org ON org.unique_key = fo.dimension__order__responsible_organisation_key
LEFT OUTER JOIN analyticsdatamart_gen_nontemporal_v1.dimension_work_sites site ON site.unique_key = fo.dimension__order__responsible_work_site_key  LEFT OUTER JOIN analyticsdatamart_gen_nontemporal_v1.dimension_priorities prio ON fo.dimension__maximum_priority_procedure__priority_key = prio.unique_key  LEFT OUTER JOIN analyticsdatamart_gen_nontemporal_v1.dimension_actors da
    ON CASE
            WHEN da.unique_key = fo.dimension__first_report__primary_releasing_actor_key IS NOT NULL
            THEN da.unique_key = fo.dimension__first_report__primary_releasing_actor_key
            ELSE da.unique_key = fo.dimension__first_dictation__dictating_actor_key
    END 
LEFT OUTER JOIN analyticsdatamart_gen_nontemporal_v1.fact_series fse ON fse.dimension__study__key = st.unique_key
LEFT OUTER JOIN analyticsdatamart_gen_nontemporal_v1.dimension_series dse ON dse.unique_key = fse.dimension__series__key
```

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: And not just a simple EXPLAIN, we need the (complete) results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) in plain text. That CASE in the JOIN conditions smells like a problem, but without a query plan know body knows.

Comment: Please provide information as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For proper answer attach full query, table structure (with indexes) and execution plan.

Original `CASE` is quite complicated, but hard to say if it's responsible for query performance without information from execution plan.

```
CASE 
WHEN da.unique_key = fo.dimension__first_report__primary_releasing_actor_key IS NOT NULL 
THEN da.unique_key = fo.dimension__first_report__primary_releasing_actor_key 
ELSE da.unique_key = fo.dimension__first_dictation__dictating_actor_key 
END
```

This case can be transformed to

```
da.unique_key =  
CASE WHEN da.unique_key = fo.dimension__first_report__primary_releasing_actor_key IS NOT NULL 
  THEN fo.dimension__first_report__primary_releasing_actor_key 
  ELSE fo.dimension__first_dictation__dictating_actor_key 
END
```

or even

```
da.unique_key = coalesce (fo.dimension__first_report__primary_releasing_actor_key ,fo.dimension__first_dictation__dictating_actor_key)
```

This should give a optimizer (and everybody else) better understanding which column (in da table) is key for joining

Comment: Thank you I chose your last option and now the query runs in lightening speed!